# Blender is changing the orientation of an object when I import it with a script to a collection

Tags: scripting

I have made a script that can create a procedural forest. It works wonderfully on the top surfaces, but the trees are also procedural at the base of the ground material and for some reason they spawn lying horizontally. If someone can help me I would be very grateful.

[image: The collections]
[image]

This is the part where the trees are added:

[image: the problem should be here]

This is the entire code, the problem should be at the end:

```
#Función que evalua los bordes

import bpy
    
def comprobar_borde(modulo1,modulo2,dirección:tuple):
    
    vertices_modulo1=set()
    vertices_modulo2=set()
    
    X,Y=dirección
     
    if X==0:
     
        for v in modulo1.data.vertices:
            y=round(v.co.y,1)
            if y== 1*Y:
                x=round(v.co.x,1)
                z=round(v.co.z,1)
                vertices_modulo1.add((x,z))    
        
        for v in modulo2.data.vertices:
            y=round(v.co.y,1)
            if y== -1*Y:
                x=round(v.co.x,1)
                z=round(v.co.z,1)
                vertices_modulo2.add((x,z))   
    else:
        
        for v in modulo1.data.vertices:
            x=round(v.co.x,1)
            if x== 1*X:
                y=round(v.co.y,1)
                z=round(v.co.z,1)
                vertices_modulo1.add((y,z))    
        
        for v in modulo2.data.vertices:
            x=round(v.co.x,1)
            if x== -1*X:
                y=round(v.co.y,1)
                z=round(v.co.z,1)
                vertices_modulo2.add((y,z))
        
    if vertices_modulo1==vertices_modulo2:
        
        return True
    else:
        return False
    
def indice_conexiones(tileset:list):
    
    direcciónes= [(0,2),(0,-2),(2,0),(-2,0)]
    
    indice={}
    
    for t in tileset:
        indice[t.name]={}
        for dir in direcciónes:
            indice[t.name][dir]=[]
            for t2 in tileset:
                if comprobar_borde(t,t2,dir)==True:
                    indice[t.name][dir].append(t2.name)
        
    return indice

    
import math

def rotaciones(tileset:list):
    
    #si ya existe la coleccion, borrarla:
    coll=bpy.data.collections.get("TilesetCompleto")
    if coll !=None:
        for obj in coll.objects:
            m=obj.data
            bpy.data.objects.remove(obj)
            bpy.data.meshes.remove(m)
        bpy.data.collections.remove(coll)
    
    #colección para las rotaciones:
    coll=bpy.data.collections.new("TilesetCompleto")
    bpy.context.scene.collection.children.link(coll)
    
    #añadimos los objetos
    for t in tileset:
        
        t1=bpy.data.objects.new(t.name+'_0',t.data.copy())
        coll.objects.link(t1)
        
        t2=bpy.data.objects.new(t.name+'_90',t.data.copy())
        t2.rotation_euler[2]=math.radians(90)
        coll.objects.link(t2)
        
        t3=bpy.data.objects.new(t.name+'_180',t.data.copy())
        t3.rotation_euler[2]=math.radians(180)
        coll.objects.link(t3)
        
        t4=bpy.data.objects.new(t.name+'_270',t.data.copy())
        t4.rotation_euler[2]=math.radians(270)
        coll.objects.link(t4)
        
    #aplicamos la rotacion y los nombres de las mallas
    for obj in coll.objects:
        obj.data.name=obj.name
        obj.select_set(True)
        bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(rotation=True)
    

#Generación cuadricula

import random

def grid_vacio(alto,ancho):
    
    grid=[]
    for i in range(alto):
        fila=[]
        for j in range(ancho):
            fila.append('##None##')
        grid.append(fila)
    
    return grid

def adyacentes_vacios(grid:list,celda:tuple):
    
    direcciones=[ (0,2), (0,-2), (2,0), (-2,0) ]
    vacios = []
    y,x = celda
    
    #por cada dirección, si la siguiente celda está vacía la guardamos
    for dir in direcciones:
        dy,dx = dir
        siguiente = (y+dy,x+dx)
        if siguiente[0] in range(len(grid)) and siguiente[1] in range(len(grid[0])):
            valor=grid[siguiente[0]][siguiente[1]]
            if valor=='##None##':
                vacios.append(siguiente)
                
    return vacios

def adyacentes_ocupados(grid:list,celda:tuple):
    
    direcciones=[ (0,2), (0,-2), (2,0), (-2,0) ]
    ocupados=[]
    
    #por cada dirección, si la siguiente celda está ocupada la guardamos junto con la dirección
    y,x=celda
    for dir in direcciones:
        dy,dx=dir
        siguiente=(y+dy,x+dx)
        if siguiente[0] in range(len(grid)) and siguiente[1] in range(len(grid[0])):
            valor=grid[siguiente[0]][siguiente[1]]
            if valor!='##None##':
                ocupados.append(((-dy,-dx),valor)) 
                
    return ocupados
        
    
#Programa principal

    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    #sets modulares
    tileset_inicial = []
    tileset_completo = []
    
    #rellenamos el primer set
    for obj in bpy.data.collections["TilesetInicial"].objects:
        tileset_inicial.append(obj)
    
    #generamos las rotaciones y rellenamos el segundo set
    rotaciones(tileset_inicial)
    
    for obj in bpy.data.collections["TilesetCompleto"].objects:
        tileset_completo.append(obj)

    #generamos el indice con la informacion de adyacencia
    indice = indice_conexiones(tileset_completo)
    
    #grid vacío
    alto,ancho = (20,20)
    grid = grid_vacio(alto,ancho)
    
    #colección para el terreno
    coll = bpy.data.collections.get("Terreno")
    if coll != None:
        for obj in coll.objects:
            bpy.data.objects.remove(obj)
        bpy.data.collections.remove(coll)
    
    terreno = bpy.data.collections.new('Terreno')
    bpy.context.scene.collection.children.link(terreno)
    
    #primera casilla
    inicio = (0,0)
    y,x = inicio
    
    modulo = random.choice(tileset_completo).data
    grid[y][x] = modulo.name
    obj = bpy.data.objects.new(modulo.name + '_Linked', modulo)
    terreno.objects.link(obj)
    obj.location = (x,y,0)
    
    #bucle de generación
    cola = []
    
    celdas_vecinas = adyacentes_vacios(grid,inicio)
    cola.extend(celdas_vecinas)
    
    while len(cola) > 0:
        
        siguiente = cola.pop()
        y,x = siguiente
        
        celdas_vecinas = adyacentes_ocupados(grid,siguiente)
        
        posibles = []
        
        # posibles = [["Esquina_270","Base_0",...],["Esquina_270"]]
        
        for cel in celdas_vecinas: # cel = ((0,-1),"Base_0") | (dirección,modulo)
            dir,nombre = cel 
            posibles.append(indice[nombre][dir])
            
        modulos_en_todos = list(set.intersection(*map(set, posibles)))
        
        #elegir el siguiente módulo al azar
        if len(modulos_en_todos) > 0:
            modulo = random.choice(modulos_en_todos)
            grid[y][x] = modulo
        
            #colocar una copia del modulo en el terreno
            modulo_m = bpy.data.objects[modulo].data
            obj = bpy.data.objects.new(modulo + '_Linked', modulo_m)
        
            terreno.objects.link(obj)
            obj.location = (y,x,0)
        
            #añadir sus adyacentes a la cola
            celdas_vecinas = adyacentes_vacios(grid,siguiente)
            for cel in celdas_vecinas:
                if cel not in cola:
                    cola.append(cel)

    #detalles sobre el terreno
    coll=bpy.data.collections.get("Detalles")
    if coll != None:
        for obj in coll.objects:
            bpy.data.objects.remove(obj)
        bpy.data.collections.remove(coll)
      
    detalles = bpy.data.collections.new('Detalles')
    bpy.context.scene.collection.children.link(detalles)
    
    assets=[]

    #rellenamos la lista de opciones
    for obj in bpy.data.collections["Assets"].objects:
        assets.append(obj)
    
    for obj in bpy.data.collections.get('Terreno').objects:
        obj_loc=obj.location
        for face in obj.data.polygons:
            loc=obj_loc+face.center
            #si el material de la cara es el material hierba
            if face.material_index==2:
                if random.randint(1,5)==1:
                    #añadimos un asset al azar
                    asset=random.choice(assets).data
                    obj=bpy.data.objects.new(asset.name+"_Linked",asset)
                    detalles.objects.link(obj)
                    obj.location=loc
                    obj.rotation_euler[2]=math.radians(random.choice([0,90,180,270]))
```